# HibernateTransactionManager(Spring) with multiple Session Factories

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions

I have a DAO implementation that uses a HibernateTransactionManager for transaction management and the application has 2 session factories. I am getting an exception at the transactionManager.commit() line below. **Does performing Hibernate operations within a transaction manager related to a different session factory cause problems?**

```
TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
try{
    doHibernateStuff1();  //Does Hibernate stuff with session
                          //factory related to Tx Manager
    doHibernateStuff2();  //Does Hibernate stuff with session 
                          //factory not related to Tx Manager
}
catch(DataAccessException){
 transactionManager.rollback(status);
}
transactionManager.commit(status); //Exception happens here.
```

The exception appears to be trying to perform the operations in  `doHibernateStuff2();` again in the `txManager.commit()`.

If you want to suggest a kludge and/or proper way of dealing with this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using XA drivers to connect to the two data sources involved in the transaction?  Can't work otherwise.

Comment: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver and net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver; I'm not sure these are XA or not.

Comment: No,net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource is the jTDS XA driver class; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335(SQL.90).aspx for Microsoft's XA driver.  (You have to install DLL for the latter.)

Comment: Why are you using both the jTDS and Microsoft drivers?  Why not just one or the other?

Comment: This was work that had been previously but I don't believe there is a reason for this.

Comment: jTDS is pure type IV; no DLLs needed for XA driver.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I've encountered similar problem. I presume that Brandon has **2 session factories** for **different data sources** and he's using **HibernateTransactionManager**. And I believe that using such manager is the problem. From what I've read HibernateTransactionManager isn't able to work with 2 different session factories. Instead he should use a different manager like JTA transaction manager. But only if he needs access to both data sources in one transaction. Otherwise the solution should be using extra manager for every session factory like mentioned in the link bellow:

[similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700160/spring-hibernatetransactionmanager-handling-multiple-datasources)