# Multiple sessions for same data source in single Hibernate @Transactional: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm working on a Spring Boot application that uses Hibernate and mysql for persistence. I get the following errors randomly from `@Transactional` `SELECT` queries called from `@Service` layer.

```
Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed,
    java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:930)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1602)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor148.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:71)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer.invoke(ResetAbandonedTimer.java:63)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:71)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:153)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:41)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.commit(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112)", " [wrapped]
    org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:180)", " [wrapped] org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:187)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584)", " [wrapped] org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit
    Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:588)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:484)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy313.getLibrary(Unknown Source)
```

The service method is annotated with `@Transactional` and it calls two different repositories that use different `SessionFactory` instances. (No need to annotate it with `@Transactional`, I guess, but that does not explain why it fails, right?). I think that may be the root cause of the error but I'm unable to consistently reproduce the error. Seems like depending on the load or something else that I could not spot yet. I'd love to hear any idea about the possible cause, suggestions on how to debug or further reading.

Already read those:

- [Spring: HibernateTransactionManager handling multiple datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700160/spring-hibernatetransactionmanager-handling-multiple-datasources)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch10s03.html
- [Spring-Boot How to properly inject javax.validation.Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604540/spring-boot-how-to-properly-inject-javax-validation-validator)

**SessionFactories**

There are two sessionFactories for the same mysql connection. One session perform lifecycle event validation while other does not.

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    //...
    return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
}

@Bean(name = "otherSessionFactory")
public SessionFactory otherSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    //...
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none");
    return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
}
```

**PlatformTransactionManager**

There is only one `PlatformTransactionManager` using the unnamed/default sessionFactory. I'm not sure how the otherSessionFactory's sessions are working without setting the `PlatformTransactionManager`. In transactional test methods, the operations are not rolled back, that's why I assume otherSessionFactory's sessions do not have a `PlatformTransactionManager`.

```
@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
//...
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
}
```

**Repositories**

```
@Bean
public BooksRepository booksRepository(@Qualifier("otherSessionFactory") sessionFactory) {
    return new HibernateBooksRepository(sessionFactory);
}

@Bean
public AuthorsRepository authorsRepository(sessionFactory) {
    return new HibernateAuthorsRepository(sessionFactory);
}
```

**Service**

```
@Transactional
public Library getLibrary() {
        List<Author> authors = authorsRepository.getAll();
        List<Book> books = booksRepository.getAll(); // throws Exception
        //...
}
```

Comment: Why are you using two session factories? Are they connecting to the same database? If not then you may need to use JTA transaction manager for distributed transactions. If they connect to the same database then you may try to use only one

Comment: There are JSR-303 validators on the classes that are also being used as DB Entities. These validators have @Autowired service objects which fails when Hibernate does the validation since it cannot inject the objects. In short, it is used to fix "Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator" errors as in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604540/spring-boot-how-to-properly-inject-javax-validation-validator. That's why I'm trying to solve it with two session factories. Thanks for the JTA txManager, I'll read on that.